# Performance differences between jconn2 and jconn3

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, sybase

I have tested jconn2 and jconn3 on same application which is connected to sybase ase15.03 server . But I encountered the really big performance differences between these two api. For example I have run a simple select query on a big table  (which contains 7051328 rows 20 cols). JCONN2 returns the resultset in 5.3sec but jconn3 returns the resultset for same query in 11.6sec.(I  tested more complex queries too and still have differences. ) So, actually I couldn't find any clear explanation about this differences. Could anyone explain this?

Note: I tested both jonn2 and jconn3 on same application and same sybase server.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: jconn is the Sybase JDBC driver, right?

Comment: yes skaffman. and thx for jdbc tag. i missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by difference in implementation of DateTime type of columns in resultsets data of Jconn2 and Jconn3. One of them is fast and incorrect and another is slow but correct. The incorrectness is related to taking/not taking into account local timezones.

Have you tested difference with samples of data without any DateTime columns ?.

Comment: actually,no. I will test this case soon and write the result to here. hanks.

Comment: In later version of Jconn, Sybase used Calendar object, which is slow. Well it will be great to see your result. Appreciate